# How to create a file with symbols in its name

Tags: unix

How can I create a file starting from `$SHELL`, using quotes like `" "`,`' '`, `\`?

I tried, but it's not working.

Comment: Do you mean "special characters" by "symbols"? If not, what else? Which specific commands have you tried, and what were the results?

Comment: [nitesh@ical ~]$ mkdir '$SHELL'
the above command will work, it allows you to create the directory with special symbols like "$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the special characters using the shell escape `\` e.g.

```
touch \'test
```

Comment: in addition: if you want to create files starting with `-` you can use `touch -- -myfile` or `touch ./-myfile`